# How to get the previous url & redirect from controller

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, url, controllers, redirect

How can I detect the URL and store it then use it on the Controller for Redirect. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get current URL in Magento use below code.

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()
```

But i think your requirement is to get the previous URL & redirect from controller. If it so use below code.

```
$this->_redirectReferer()
```

Comment: Thanks it is correct to use the $this->_redirectReferer() on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In controller you can using redirect when using one of the following functions:

```
/**
 * Set redirect into responce
 *
 * @param   string $path
 * @param   array $arguments
 */
protected function _redirect($path, $arguments=array())
{

}

/**
 * Set redirect url into response
 *
 * @param   string $url
 * @return  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 */
protected function _redirectUrl($url)
{
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set referer url for redirect in response
 *
 * @param   string $defaultUrl
 * @return  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 */
protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Generate url by route and parameters in Adminhtml
 *
 * @param   string $route
 * @param   array $params
 * @return  string
 */
public function getUrl($route='', $params=array())
{
    return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

Get URL of a path:
`Mage::getUrl($path, $arguments);`

**Example**

You want redirect to controller of path: `sales/order/view` with params `order_id=8`

`$this->_redirect('sales/order/view', array('order_id' => 8));`